# How do you solve a problem like a mystery switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have a couple of switches in my house that I can’t determine what they do. How do I figure out what they are connected to, or otherwise troubleshoot a mystery switch to try to get it to work again?

Answer (score 4):

Start by opening them up and seeing if they've been bypassed.  Sometimes people eliminate a switch, and then don't bother removing the switch because they don't want to be left with an empty hole.  If you find a bypassed switch, *un-bypass* it.

Some switches actually switch power to a receptacle.  This is often done instead of an overhead ceiling light, because that saves the builder a couple of dollars. *There's a complication:* As you know, most US receptacles have 2 sockets. **The sockets can be split to be separately controlled**: if you ever hear something about "tabs" on sockets, that's what that's all about.  It's common to split and have one socket switched and the other always-hot.  So you need to check 'em both... on each recep.

Sometimes, novices replace receptacles (they don't like the color) and they *don't even realize* that tabs are a thing, so they don't break off the tab like the old one was.  This will have the effect of defeating the switch. Spotting these is a bit of a trick, and the only way is to open up the receptacles and look for odd wiring.

Comment: yeah if someone replaced a split outlet and didn't remove the tab  that would bypass the switch.

Comment: @Jasen *good point*...

Comment: Where are the switches located? Are there outlets on the eves for Christmas lights?   Maybe crawl space lights?

Comment: Yup, my mother-in-law's home had a switch that was a mystery to her for 15 years, in the hallway. I discovered that it controlled a light fixture in the attic.